# SSRS: removing javaScript from a report link when exported to PDF

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report (`SSRS`) that has links on the individual actions. 
The `javaScript` is there so that when used inside my web applciation, the new drill down report opens in a new popup window.

ALAS, when exporting the report to PDF the links (drill down) no longer work because PDF doesn't handle the javaScript...

1. How do I clean up links in the exported `PDF` from `javaScript`?
2. Or, how do I tell `SSRS` to turn off the link completely when exporting?

Code:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & Parameters!WebServer.Value & "/pages/reports/somePage.aspx?params=" & Parameters!dfb_DataSet_GN4.Value) & "','Blue','location=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,height=704,width=985'))"
```

Answer (score 1):

bit old but may help others that come here.

=IIf(Parameters!RenderURLForExcelOrPDF.Value = True, "--URL--", "javascript:void(window.open('--URL--'))")

from :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/4ba08797-4e37-4cbb-8b0a-d8e383a69da4

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be done but I think not. 
However, you can have a hidden parameter that by default uses the javascript link, and in susbcriptions would use the normal link.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me

```
=IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive=false, Fields!Link.Value, "javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!Link.Value & "','_blank'))")
```